# Find the equation of a plane tangent at a point of a surface and also parallel to another given plane.

Tags: calculus

So, my Calculus is a bit rusty, and I don't remember how to do this. Here's the question:

> Let $\pi_1$ be a plane tangent to the surface modeled by:
>
> $$z = f(x,y) = x^2 + 3y^2 - 4x + 4y - 5,\\\text{ with }-10\leq z\leq 10.$$
> If $\pi_1$ is parallel to the plane $\pi_2$, with equation $8x - 4y - 2z + 5 = 0$, what's the equation of plane $\pi_1$?

I know that once upon a time I knew how to do this kind of question. But for now, I don't have a clue. Can anyone help?

Comment: If $\phi = f(x,y)-z$ then $(x,y,z)$ on the plane is normal to the gradient $Grad(\phi)$.

Comment: What made you want to do this problem if you are not taking Calculus?

Comment: I have already concluded Graduation. And I'm re-studying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if two planes are parallel, then so are the corresponding normal vectors. Define the given surface as $z = f(x, y)$. A normal vector to the tangent plane at a point $(a, b, f(a, b))$ is
$$ \langle f_x(a, b), f_y(a, b), -1\rangle. $$
A normal vector to the plane $8x - 4y - 2z + 5 = 0$ is $\langle 4, -2, -1\rangle$. You have two equations to solve now:
\begin{align*} 
f_x = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & = 2x - 4 \text{ and so } 2a - 4 = 4 \\ 
f_y = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} & = 6y + 4 \text{ and so } 6b + 4 = -2. 
\end{align*}
This yields $a = 4$ and $b = -1$. Finally, $f(a, b) = f(4, -1) = -6$ and the desired equation of the tangent plane is
$$ z - f(a, b) = f_x(a, b)\cdot (x - a) + f_y(a, b)\cdot (y - b), $$
or
$$ z + 6 = 4(x - 4) - 2(y + 1). $$

Comment: Question asks for help, not a full solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\pi_1: 8x-4y-2z+c_1 = 0 $$
To say that $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are parallel is to say that they never intersect. By symmetry, normals to these planes will also not intersect and hence are parallel. (It is easy to find the line of intersection of two planes if their normals are given and it is given that they intersect). Then the direction numbers of $\pi_1$ are the same as that of $\pi_2$.
$$f(x,y)=x^2+3y^2−4x+4y−5$$
The gradient - $\left( \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}, -1 \right) = (2x-4, 6y+4,-1 )$ is normal to the surface. Solve this to get, $x=4, y=-1.$ The required plane $\pi_1$ has the equation - $(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0) \cdot \left( \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}, -1 \right) = 0 $ (because the normal to the graph is also a normal to the tangent plane at that point) or $(x-4,y+1, z-6) \cdot (4,-2,-1) = 0$ i.e., $4x-2y-z-12=0$

Comment: Question asks for help. This is not help.

Comment: I see. From my current understanding, a solution would be more concise than my answer. Your comment on the question should suffice o give enough intuition to get started. I agree.